# grails database-migration - changelog.xml not updated by dbm-gorm-diff with --add

Tags: grails

We want to automate the migration of Domain object changes through to the live database, by augmenting our Jenkins (Hudson) build.

I have experimented with the database-migration plugin, by generating a changelog from the domain objects, making a change and generating a difflog. When generating groovy files, it works as defined, and changelog.groovy gets updated to include the difflog.

However, I decided to generate the liquibase xml files, on the basis that there is Ant support for liquibase. My conclusion was that I would have to create a headless (batch) Grails app in order to use the groovy files in a build script.

However, when I run "dbm-gorm-dif difflog.xml --add" the changelog.xml is not updated to include the difflog.xml. Yet the documentation implies that the updating applies to groovy and xml files. I can add it manually, and it works, but I need to automate this process.

I have set the following in Config.groovy
grails.plugin.databasemigration.changelogFileName = 'changelog.xml'

Is there something I haven't done, or is the manual not quite correct?

Regards, John

Comment: the command should be dbm-gorm-diff difflog.xml --add ( note two -- or the flag gets ignored. ). Is that a typo?

Comment: Tomas, Thanks, it was a typo. I have corrected the original text

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 1.2.2, so is no longer a problem when using this version or later.